# regex (and function ?) to match particular text

Tags: regex

I have a log  that generate this kind of entry

```
<135>Oct 20 11:10:49 Oct 20 11:10:56.085 CRE: authid_log_card()- authid: 471178EAB6, type: M35XX info: Sam Smith (Keyholder) (card #1)
<135>Oct 20 11:17:15 Oct 20 11:17:21.913 CRE: authid_log_card()- authid: 6199559ABC, type: M22XX info: John Dawson (user #3)
<135>Oct 20 11:20:15 Oct 20 11:17:21.913 CRE: authid_log_card()- authid: 6199559ABC, type: M27XX info: Access denied
```

I need to find a regex able to catch the name "John Dawson" and "Same Smith" and also the "Access denied" that have no anchor point but its terminate it self
I tried using this

info:\s(.*?)\s(|info:(\s.*?)$

but it create "two captuing group" and the software were i need to pass this log is not able to identify two capturing group each time

Any idea how to better compose this regex?

Thank you

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew What does `\k` match (`\K` being the opposite I guess)?

Comment: @sp00m: `\K` in PCRE/Boost/Onigmo is a match reset operator, there is no `\k` as an opposite construct.

Comment: Mrblack, do you really need the whitespace to be captured in the second scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current regex `info:\s(.*?)\s\(|info:(\s.*?)$` matches one of the two alternatives:

- `info:\s(.*?)\s\(` - `info:`, followed with a whitespace, then any 0+ chars other than line break chars as few as possible are captured into Group 1 up to a whitespace followed with `(`
- `info:(\s.*?)$` - matches `info:` and then captures a whitespace and any 0+ chars other than line break chars into Group 1, as few as possible but up to the end of string.

You may actually use one capturing group to match any 0+ chars as few as possible up to whitespace + `(` or end of string with

```
info:\s*(.*?)(?=\s*\(|$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/a36e9f/2)

**Details**

- `info:` - a `info:` substring
- `\s*`- + whitesoaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible up to but not including...
- `(?=\s*\(|$)` - 0+ whitespaces and `(` (with `\s*\(`) or (`|`) the end of string (`$`) (or line if you are using a tool like Grok or a text editor.)

Comment: Another way (more efficient but less readable): [`info:\s*(\S*(?:\s[^\s(]+)*)`](https://regex101.com/r/a36e9f/3), will work with Go regex engine since it has no lookaround in it.